# Sbt unresolved dependencies invalid character

Tags: dependencies, sbt, invalid-characters

Because of my first name containing a unicode char, I had problems using SBT on it.

```
  io problem while parsing ivy file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sca
  la-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.2/scala-reflect-2.10.2.pom: Path contains invalid cha
  racter: Ù

  (...)

  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  :: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.2: not found
  :: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.2: not found
  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I ran into the [following solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/Zof5BjHngbA), which says to add the following to sbtconfig.txt:

```
-Dsbt.ivy.home=C:/Users/Mikael/.ivy2/
-Divy.home=C:/Users/Mikael/.ivy2/
```

where `Mikael` is a symlink for `Mikaël`.
This does not work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also edit `sbtopts`, change the line

```
#-ivy ~/.ivy2
```

to

```
-ivy c:/Users/Mikael/.ivy2
```

where `Mikael` is a symlink for `Mikaël`